# XSL FO LIST has empty white space

Tags: xslt, xmltable

I have the following xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="TABLE">
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
    <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>         
    </fo:table-body>
 </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="LIST">
    <fo:list-block>
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:block margin-left="0.03in"> &#x2022;</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
                <fo:block margin-left="0.10in">
                    <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>
```

But in the output of the table, when LIST template is called, there is white space in the top and end within each cell as if I have given padding top/bottom. Please help me with this. If I have any other tag other than LIST, then there is no space encountered.

Comment: Isn't it a default of lists to have a space on top and bottom?

Comment: Seems to be the default behavior. But what could be the solution for not having space? I tried padding-top="-0.15in". This worked for top. But not for bottom.

Comment: if `padding-bottom="-0.15in"` will not work, try `margin-bottom="-0.15in"`

Comment: Thank you:) That worked. I was trying padding within table-cell.